# 'hello world' chrome extension takes 2 seconds to open every time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm making an extremely basic google chrome extension. All it does is basically open a small html popup that has a h1 hello world. However, every time I try to open it it takes nearly 2 seconds to open the popup. I'm on a decent laptop with a 4th gen i5 and an SSD, so this shouldn't happen. Also, Other extensions like pushbullet and lastpass with easilly more complex code than mine take less time to open their popups.

I thought this was because I was running it as a unpackaged extension, but even after packaging into a crx file it still takes 1-2 seconds to open the popup. Is there something I'm missing to optimize this correctly so that it opens nearly instantly? Here is my code

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "Insert Description Here",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "app/index.html",
        "default_title": "Hello World"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KeePass Companion</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some recent Chrome versions featured a similar bug for a while when `[x] Hardware acceleration` was enabled in the Settings, try unchecking it until the issue is fixed in some future version of Chrome. Or try updating/reverting your graphics card driver.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I think this is just an issue with Chrome itself. Try turning off hardware acceleration and see if it improves.